# reversing argument list and lost doublequotes

Tags: bash, arguments, imagemagick-convert, quoting

Revisiting a simple script to append images together, because spaces in paths are problematic.

The output is correct, but the doublequoting of the path/filenames is not present, so convert fails.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple syntax fix. Suggestions?
...Maybe I'd be better off using the mode arg before the file args, and bumping it off with shift?

```
#!/bin/bash
# BETLOG - 2015-05-05--22-17-35
#
# usage:
# betlogImageAppend.sh %F row/wor/col/loc
# # 
mode=${!#} #last arg
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}" #strip last arg: mode
#echo -ne "\\n\\n0 @=${@}\\n\\n"
case "$mode" in
    row) 
        mode="+append"
        in=$@
    ;;
    wor)
        mode="+append"
        in="$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | tac)"
    ;;
    col)
        mode="-append"
        in=$@
    ;;
    loc)
        mode="-append"
#         in=$(printf '%s\n' ${@} | tac)
#         in=`printf '%s\n' "${*}" | tac`
        in=$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | tac)
    ;;
esac

echo "convert "${in}" $mode $(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S).jpg"
# # # convert ${in} $mode $(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S).jpg
```

I was testing the 'loc' (reversed column), hence the various trials.
FYI: row/wor/col/loc = row/reversed row/column/reversed column

Comment: Can you post example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
in='smth with space.jpg
another with space.jpg'
convert "${in}" ...
```

Then `"$in"` is interpreted as **single** one argument. That means that `convert` will search for a single file named `smth with space.jpg\nanother with space.jpg` and not for two files. If you were to write `convert $in ...` then `in` gets expanded and is not enclosed, space and newline are interpreted as separators, so it gets 6 files, ie. file named `smth`, file named `with` and so on. As a solution to this problem we can use bash arrays and always remember to properly escape your arguments.

```
mode=${!#} #last arg
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}" #strip last arg: mode
case "$mode" in
row) mode="+append"; in=("$@"); ;;
                         # `for i;` is a shorter version of `for i in "$@";`
wor) mode="+append"; in=(); for i; do in=("$i" "${in[@]}"); done; ;; 
col) mode="-append"; in=("$@"); ;;
loc) mode="-append"; in=(); for i; do in=("$i" "${in[@]}"); done; ;;
esac

printf "arg: '%s'\n" convert "${in[@]}" "$mode" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S).jpg"
# convert "${in[@]}" "$mode" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S).jpg"
```

Such script should work with any filenames, with spaces or with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, thanks. That nailed it. I knew my array-fu was failing me.

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage:
# betlogImageAppend.sh %F row/wor/col/loc
mode=${!#} #last arg
set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}" #strip last arg: mode
case "$mode" in
    row) mode="+append"; in=("$@"); ;;
    wor) mode="+append"; in=(); for i; do in=("$i" "${in[@]}"); done; ;; # `for i;` is a shorter version of `for i in "$@";`
    col) mode="-append"; in=("$@"); ;;
    loc) mode="-append"; in=(); for i; do in=("$i" "${in[@]}"); done; ;;
esac
convert "${in[@]}" "$mode" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S).jpg"
```